# Calculate date range match into Java

Tags: java, date-range, localdatetime

I want to implement this code to check if a user is subscribed to a service:

```
public String calculateSubscription(String email) {

    Optional<Subscription> subscriptionsByUserEmail = subscriptionService.findSubscriptionsByUserEmail(email);
    if (subscriptionsByUserEmail.isPresent()) {
      Subscription subscription = subscriptionsByUserEmail.get();

      LocalDateTime startAt = subscription.getStartAt();
      LocalDateTime endAt = subscription.getEndAt();
      LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

      if(/* do here comparison */){
        return "subscribed";
      }
    }
    return "unsubscribed";
  }
```

Into database I store 2 fields:

```
@Column(name = "start_at")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime startAt;

@Column(name = "end_at")
@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)
private LocalDateTime endAt;
```

I need to check if `now` variable is matched between the time interval `startAt` and `endAt`.

***How could this check be implemented into the if statement?***

***EDIT:***

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(localDateTime)
                .map(Timestamp::valueOf)
                .orElse(null);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp timestamp) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(timestamp)
                .map(Timestamp::toLocalDateTime)
                .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `LocalDateTime` is not the right class for your times. If the subscription starts and and ends at certain times, use `Instant`, or you may use `ZonedDateTime`. A `LocalDateTime` does not define a point in time.

Comment: Can you show me code example please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two points:

1. Don’t use `LocalDateTime` for a point in time. Anyone reading it will be free to interpret it in any time zone they can think of, for a variation of interpretations of 24 to 26 hours. `Instant` is the class to use for a point in time. It has `isBefore` and `isAfter` methods just like `LocalDateTime`, so the code will not be different. Alternatives that also do define a point in time include `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`.
2. With `Optional` don’t use its `isPresent` and `get` methods (except in rare cases). They are low-level, and by far the most often we can obtain more elegant code with higher-level methods.

I am rather into method chaining with `Optional`, so my code would look like:

```
public String calculateSubscription(String email) {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    return subscriptionService.findSubscriptionsByUserEmail(email)
            .filter(sub -> ! sub.getStartAt().isAfter(now) && sub.getEndAt().isAfter(now))
            .map(sub -> "subscribed")
            .orElse("unsubscribed");
}
```

This works if `getStartAt()` and `getEndAt()` return `Instant`. For consistent results in corner cases I read the clock only once (not twice within the filter condition). Standard interpretation of a time interval is half-open, from start inclusive to end exclusive, so my code uses this. I am using “not after” to mean “on or before”. You may not need this precision in your case.

For storing a point in time into your database, with most database engines you need a `timestamp with time zone`.

### Establish points in time if you can and only if you can

Edit: To elaborate a bit, a date and time of day, which are what a `LocalDateTime` gives us, do not establish a point in time. June 30 11:45 in Tokyo is 16 hours before June 30 11:45 in Los Angeles, for example. So for a point in time we additionally need either a time zone or a UTC offset.

If your database can be made to provide a point in time, typically through a `timestamp with time zone` as mentioned, we’re happy. Exactly how to retrieve it into Java depends on your JPA version and implementation, so I’d rather not try to be specific on that point. You may or may not need to use `OffsetDateTime` (or even `ZonedDateTime`) rather than `Instant` in Java *or* to provide a different custom converter from the one you are using now. The latter may be as easy using `Timestamp::toInstant` instead of `Timestamp::toLocalDateTime`.

If your database only gives you date and time of day, for example if it uses its `datetime` data type and this cannot be changed, don’t try to pretend otherwise. In this case insisting on converting to `Instant` may do more harm than good. No chain is stronger than its weakest link anyway. So in this case stick to `LocalDateTime` throughout in Java. Then read the clock in this fashion:

```
    ZoneId timeZoneThatTheDatabaseAssumes = ZoneId.of("Europe/Gibraltar");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(timeZoneThatTheDatabaseAssumes);
```

Of course specify the time zone ID for the time zone that your database uses.

Comment: Hello, because the logic of the code remains almost the same your choice of a specific time class would be bound to the database used (for example how the values are stored in the specific database) ?  Thanks for your attention.

Comment: One additional question. Into Hibernate Entity I use `@Convert(converter = LocalDateTimeConverter.class)` do I need it or I can remove it? See updated post.

Comment: I had to edit it this way: `sub.getStartAt().isAfter(ChronoLocalDateTime.from(now)) && sub.getEndAt().isAfter(ChronoLocalDateTime.from(now)))` Is this valid?

Comment: I can’t get that to work. I get `java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain ChronoLocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: class java.time.Instant`. Will think and edit.

Comment: While I don’t know the precise answers to your follow-up questions, I hope that you will find my edit helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`LocalDateTime#isAfter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) and [`LocalDateTime#isBefore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-) like below :

```
if (now.isAfter(startAt) && now.isBefore(endAt)) { .... }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the requirements. @dariosicily has a point but if Chronology or the Calendar system is important for your application then it's recommended to use `compareTo`

```
  LocalDateTime startAt = subscription.getStartAt();
  LocalDateTime endAt = subscription.getEndAt();
  LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

  if(now.compareTo(startAt) == 1 && now.compareTo(endAt) == -1){
    return "subscribed";
  }
```

Comment: Right, there is also this possibility.

Answer (score 2):

You have to check that `now` is beetween `startDate` and `endDate`:

```
public String calculateSubscription(String email) { 
    Optional<Subscription> subscriptionsByUserEmail = subscriptionService.findSubscriptionsByUserEmail(email);

    String result = "unsubscribed";
    if(subscriptionsByUserEmail.isPresent()){
        Subscription subscription = subscriptionsByUserEmail.get();

        LocalDateTime startAt = subscription.getStartAt();
        LocalDateTime endAt = subscription.getEndAt();
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

        if (startAt.isBefore(now) && endAt.isAfter(now)) {
            result = "subscribed";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```